# error in uploading base64Image to azure storage by using nodejs

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-devops, node-modules, monodevelop

I am getting an error when uploading a base64Image to Azure.

Code with Node.js:

```js
var name = req.body.name;
var img = req.body.image; //this image is base64Image

var uploadOptions = {
    container: 'myphoto',
    blob: name,
    text: img
}

blobServiceClient.createBlockBlobFromText(
    uploadOptions.container,
    uploadOptions.blob,
    uploadOptions.text,
    {
        contentType: 'image/jpg',
        contentEncoding: 'base64'
    }, 
    function(error, result, response) {
        if (error) {
            res.send(error);
        }

        console.log("result", result);
    
        console.log("response", response);
    }
);
```

This is the image in Azure:
[image: the result that I got in Azure]

and this is the error I get when I open the image:
[image: the error that I got when I opened the image]

The requested image is in base64Image formatting.

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you upload base64 image to azure blob storage, I suggest you convert the image content to `Buffer` then upload it.

For example

My Base64 image

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAkGBxMTEhUTExMWFRUXGBobGBgYGRsfIBoZIBsgHSAgIB0ZISghGR0lGx0XIT....
```

2. Code

```
var name = req.body.name;
var img = req.body.image; //this image is base64Image
var matches = img.match(/^data:([A-Za-z-+\/]+);base64,(.+)$/);
var type = matches[1];
var buffer = Buffer.from(matches[2], "base64");
var uploadOptions = {
    container: 'test',
    blob: name,
    text: buffer
}
blobServiceClient.createBlockBlobFromText(
  uploadOptions.container,
  uploadOptions.blob,
  uploadOptions.text,
  {
    contentSettings: {
      contentType: type,
    },
  }, 
    function(error, result, response) {
        if (error) {
            res.send(error);
        }

        console.log("result", result);
    
        console.log("response", response);
    }
);
```

My result.
[image]